# bypassing an HTML prompt for user button click

Tags: html

I have a site that is running PHPBB forum software. When a moderator selects a post for approval, there is an HTML page that launches with the message "Are you sure you want to approve this post?". The page then requires the moderator to confirm the action by clicking a Yes button.

This is the HTML code that prompts the moderator to click the Yes button:

```
<fieldset class="submit-buttons">
  {S_HIDDEN_FIELDS}
  <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="{YES_VALUE}" class="button1" />&nbsp; 
  <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="{L_NO}" class="button2" />
</fieldset>
```

I'd like to bypass this requirement, where automatically the {YES_VALUE} is passed, as if the moderator clicked the YES button, thereby eliminating the need for the moderator to actually click anything.

Is there a way I can modify the HTML code above to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're an administrator on your PHPbb forum, you should be able to disable moderator approval in the forum settings.

Comment: Thank you Theftprevention. I'm not trying to disable moderator approval. I'm trying to disable the additional prompt that says "Are you sure you want to approve this post". This requires some hacking to the actual code.

Comment: You need to modify Javascript code, not HTML

Comment: I think same as Koala_dev, this is done via JavaScript. Search for confirm()

Comment: I'm certain their is no Java behind this. Only HTML and PHP. I'm struggling to find the PHP function that calls this HTML template file. Thats why I thought it would be easier to remove the HTML prompt and simply pass the preferred button output.